# class path resource [org/springframework/web/reactive/config/DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot

I am following https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/  on my IntelliJ.
however after I excuted spring-boot:run command, below error happens

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$WebFluxConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: **class path resource [org/springframework/web/reactive/config/DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist**

I totally followed the offical guide. So what I am missing?[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>nathan</groupId>
        <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.15</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.6</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=spring_user
spring.datasource.password=123456789
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete pom.xml and the properties file?

Comment: try to replicate with same dependencies, it is working for me, can you try recreating project

Comment: Please don't post XML as images, use the proper tags and use text instead. Currently it is totally unreadable.

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan   update pom and properties thanks

Comment: @Anil I add "<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>", still same error

Comment: @M.Deinum   I put down complete pom file, hope it is readable for you

Comment: @nathan Can you try this from commandline. mvn clean package and try running as jar

Comment: Remove the `<version>` from the dependencies and remove the `spring-web` dependency, that is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-web` which you included.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Hi, I followed your comment, the same error happens

Comment: The actual interesting question is why is it even trying to process that configuration. as you don't have anything reactive in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main class is wrong and you are using something like this:

```
SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class);
```

Please be sure that `SpringApplication.run()` method is called over your main class (**MainApplication** in below exmple):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem as @nathan but surely the error is not related to a wrong spring boot main class in my case. I see the error when I run JUnits using @SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)